# manually download pytorch and feed downloaded path to anaconda

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I tried to `conda install pytorch ...` but it doesn't even start and gives me

```
("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

I'm thinking to download the necessary file manually(safe download even if internet is slow) and then set it to anaconda so that installs directly from downloaded file instead of downloading it self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by downloading pip wheels for torch, torchvision and torchaudio etc. and doing pip installation for local wheels. Suitable Pytorch wheels can be downloaded from [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html). Now, you can simply pip install the downloaded `whl` files:

```
pip install file.whl
```

Here `file.whl` is the downloaded wheel.

Comment: ok, so this install will also work for the conda env as well? sorry I'm new at this

Comment: it should work, as long as you have activated the conda env that you want to install into. You can check where will the package be installed by running `which pip`.

Comment: you have to download it? How about linking it directly from the url?